# No nick attribute when using channel history with discordpy

Tags: python, discord.py

I am using discordpy library

When a receive a message inside my "on_message" event function, I can access the current nickname of the user on the server using `message.author.nick` or `message.author.display_name` attributes. This works perfectly fine.

But when I am listing the old messages of a channel, using the following code, the "message" object doesn't have a nick attribute (return an Exception when trying to call it), and the display_name is equal to the discord username :

```
message_history = await channel.history(limit=None).flatten()
for message in message_history:
    self.manage_banned_users_from_message(message)
```

I would like to be able to retreive nicknames even from previous message. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will give back an array of strings with the nicks from the user's message in the message history, and if it doesn't have a nick, then it takes the name (without the numbers).

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def keyword(ctx):
    messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=10).flatten()
    mem = []
    for msg in messages:
        if msg.author.nick is None:
            mem.append(str(msg.author)[:-5])
        else:
            mem.append(str(msg.author.nick))
    print(str(mem))
client.run(token)
```

Output on console (a list of nicknames):

```
['Ninja', 'Kenny', 'Ninja', 'Ninja', 'Kenny', 'Mudae', 'Audio Bot', 'Ninja', 'Kenny', 'Kenny']
```

This is different from your approach because I'm not using a class, but if this is what you wanted to do, then you could do this approach to get an array and then pass it on your function.